# Poetry: Stuck resolving dependencies with python >= 2.7

Tags: python, pip, packaging, pipenv, pyproject.toml

I have a project that build on Python 2.7 and Python 3.9.

I am using the following pyproject.toml:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["poetry_core>=1.1.4"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.poetry]
name = "MyProject"
version = "1.0.0"
description = ""
authors = [""]
readme = ""
repository = ""
homepage = ""

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=2.7"
bcrypt = "*"
pywin32 = [
    {version = "228", python = "^2.7"},
    {version = "300", python = "^3.0"}, 
]
```

When executing `poetry update`, the process stays stuck at `"Resolving dependencies..."` forever.

If I replace the python dependency by `python = "^2.7"` it works (but cannot install on python 3), and if I replace by `python = "^3.0"` it works too (but cannot install on python 2).

What should I do ?

Comment: There's no better time to drop Python 2 than now.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but things are not that easy in a company with customers.
(we plan to do it soon however).